# Making a copy of an Arraylist into a different object returning Null in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am self taught and for practice I am trying do build a card management app for a board game. I want to have an array of cards where I can remove and add cards when needed. So I opted for making it an ArrayList.  However, when I want to make a copy of the cards Arraylist to a new one called CardStack in a different class, it prints as "null". My idea for the copy is to have the original array intact and having a copy I can manipulate.

The code I have now:

In Main:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List <Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        cards.add(new Card("Cloth Making", "Orange", 50, 50, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0,
                  "Naval Warfare", 10, 1));
        // ..and ten more cards.add

        //Create a cardstack that can be manipulated
        CardStack CardStack = new CardStack(cards);
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(CardStack.toString());
            int index = scan.nextInt(); 
            CardStack.buy(index);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the CardStack class:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardStack{

    private Card[] cards; 
    Hand hand = new Hand();

    //Creates a copy of the ArrayLisy cards
    public CardStack(List<Card> cards){
        List<Card> CardStack = new ArrayList<Card>()
        CardStack.addAll(cards);
    }; 
    
    // Adds discounts to colors, points and moves card.
    public void buy (int index){
        hand.redDiscountTotal += this.cards[index].getRedDiscount();
        hand.blueDiscountTotal += this.cards[index].getBlueDiscount(); 
        hand.greenDiscountTotal += this.cards[index].getGreenDiscount();
        hand.orangeDiscountTotal += this.cards[index].getOrangeDiscount();
        hand.yellowDiscountTotal += this.cards[index].getYellowDiscount();  
        hand.pointsTotal += this.cards[index].getPoints();

        //Loop checks if CardDiscount name matches an unbought card and subtracts the discount from cost.
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
            if (this.cards[index].getCardDiscount().equals(this.cards[i].getName())){
                this.cards[i].setOriginalCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - this.cards[index].getAmountCardDiscount());
                break; 
            }
        }

        //Loop updates the cost of cards with the new discountTotal 
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Red")){
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - hand.redDiscountTotal);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Blue")){
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - hand.blueDiscountTotal);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Green")){
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - hand.greenDiscountTotal);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Orange")){
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - hand.orangeDiscountTotal);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Yellow")){
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - hand.yellowDiscountTotal);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Blue and Yellow")){
                int highestDiscount = (hand.blueDiscountTotal > hand.yellowDiscountTotal) ? hand.blueDiscountTotal : 
                     hand.yellowDiscountTotal;
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - highestDiscount);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Yellow and Orange")){
                int highestDiscount = (hand.yellowDiscountTotal > hand.orangeDiscountTotal) ? hand.yellowDiscountTotal : 
                     hand.orangeDiscountTotal;
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - highestDiscount);
            }
            if (this.cards[i].getColor().equals("Blue and Orange")){
                int highestDiscount = (hand.blueDiscountTotal > hand.orangeDiscountTotal) ? hand.blueDiscountTotal : 
                     hand.orangeDiscountTotal;
                this.cards[i].setCurrentCost(this.cards[i].getOriginalCost() - highestDiscount);

            }
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        
        return
        Arrays.toString(this.cards); 
    }
}
```

in Card class:

```java
public class Card {

    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int currentCost;
    private int originalCost;  
    private int redDiscount;
    private int blueDiscount;
    private int greenDiscount;
    private int orangeDiscount;
    private int yellowDiscount; 
    private String cardDiscount; 
    private int amountCardDiscount; 
    private int points;

    public Card(String name, String color, int currentCost, int originalCost, int redDiscount, int blueDiscount, int greenDiscount, int 
                        orangeDiscount, int yellowDiscount, String cardDiscount, int amountCardDiscount, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.currentCost = currentCost;
        this.originalCost = originalCost;
        this.redDiscount = redDiscount;
        this.blueDiscount = blueDiscount;
        this.greenDiscount = greenDiscount;
        this.orangeDiscount = orangeDiscount;
        this.yellowDiscount = yellowDiscount;
        this.cardDiscount = cardDiscount;
        this.amountCardDiscount = amountCardDiscount;
        this.points = points; 
    }
    //Followed by copy constructor, getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return 
            "Name='" + getName() + "'\n" +
            ", Color='" + getColor() + "''\n" +
            ", Cost='" + getCurrentCost() + "''\n" +
            ", Red Discount='" + getRedDiscount() + "''\n" +
            ", Blue Discount='" + getBlueDiscount() + "''\n" +
            ", Green Discount='" + getGreenDiscount() + "''\n" +
            ", Orange Discount='" + getOrangeDiscount() + "''\n" +
            ", Yellow Discount='" + getYellowDiscount() + "''\n\n";
    }
```

in Hand class

```
public class Hand {

    int redDiscountTotal = 0;
    int blueDiscountTotal = 0;
    int greenDiscountTotal = 0;
    int orangeDiscountTotal = 0;
    int yellowDiscountTotal = 0;
    int pointsTotal = 0; 
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to make a copy of the `ArrayList` cards to one in the `CardStack` class. Then when you decide to `Buy` a card from the `CardStack` the program will updated discounts according to color and remove that card from the `CardStack` `ArrayList` and add it to another `Arraylist` that will be in the `Hand` class. However, when I print `CardStack` it returns `Null`. If I move the declaration of the `CardStack` `Arraylist` outside of the constructor it still returns the same result.

Comment: In `public CardStack`, `List<Card> CardStack` is a local variable. You're not adding things to something visible after the constructor finishes.

Comment: (Aside: `new ArrayList<Card>(cards)` is a more efficient way to copy the list)

Comment: @AndyTurner, True and what would be your suggestion to fix this?

Comment: @Zachral you need to do something which lives longer than the lifetime of the execution of the constructor. You don't have a `List<Card>` field anywhere; you could add one and assign the copied list to that. Alternatively, you could add things to your `Card[] cards` field using `cards = CardStack.toArray(new Card[0]);`. Or... anything else. It depends on what you're trying to do.